# How to write a transitive sql join in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, left-join, inner-join

I want something like the following.

```
SELECT fewCols, aColFromNewTbl FROM TABLE_A AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C AS C ON A.ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN A_NEW_TABLE AS NEWTBL ON NEWTBL.ID = B.ID;
```

Somehow I'm not able to achieve this functionality. Actually above query is suppose to join **A** with **NEWTBL**, but I'm joining it with **B**, which is already joined with **A**. For my results I want them to come exclusively from the join of **NEWTBL** and **B**. I don't know how I can get desired results?

Comment: Could you edit your question with sample data and desired results?  I find it hard to follow the logic that you are looking for.

Comment: I don't quite get it too. Please add some more information. In Any case, in your above query, the INNER JOIN will eliminate all rows where you have data in TABLE_A but not in TABLE_B. In other words - you can also use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN TABLE_B.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need this:

```
SELECT fewCols, aColFromNewTbl
FROM TABLE_A AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B AS B
    INNER JOIN A_NEW_TABLE AS NEWTBL
    ON NEWTBL.ID = B.ID
ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C AS C
ON A.ID = C.ID;
```

Comment: DB2 will throw an error for this - you need to nest in parenthesis from before `TABLE_B` to before `ON A.ID = B.ID`, and you have to alias it (the enclosed section) too.  While I usually use this form for clarity's sake (and to simplify later joining conditions), it's not actually required.

Comment: No, the query is correct as is. On contrary, if you add the parenthesis and alias it then there will be syntax error (parenthesis alone is ok).

Comment: ... according to [the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_joinedtable.html), the only clause that's valid after `JOIN` is `ON`.  The bottom row in the diagram says that you have to wrap the _entire_ section (`JOIN` and `ON`) in parenthesis to be valid.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, your are wrong. Between `JOIN` and `ON` is `table-reference`. And according to [the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_tablereference.dita?lang=en) `table-reference` might be another `joined-table`. You can **optionally** wrap `joined-table` in parenthesis, as I already said it is valid. Invalid is aliasing it as you suggested.

Comment: @dened I just want to confirm one thing. The way you joined TABLE_B with NEW_TBL, fine. What about the TABLE_A and TABLE_B? I can see that we have the ON clause following by the INNER JOIN's. So both will work independent of each other and this is the way to write a transitive Join. Where we join a table on the fly? Thanks for your help. There was no syntax error in it. Just needs some explanation from an expert.